# How to reduce screen brightness on Sony Laptop using Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, brightness, vaio, sony

I am a complete novice to Linux and just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Sony Viao E-series laptop having NVidia graphics card.

For the life of me, I can't seem to get the screen brightness down (The screen brightness is full right now).

I have tried a bunch of different methods given online (even on this website) and have installed/downloaded a ton of material (possibly all useless) but nothing seems to have helped.

Comment: did you try the gui method of changing the screen brightness by clicking battery applet on top panel?

Comment: You should probably elaborate on what you've done, not just "I have tried a bunch of different methods".

Comment: works perfectly on SONY VAIO VPCCW1S1E - thank you so much, I was geet

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Terminal (ctrl+alt+T)
2. `$ sudo apt-get install xbacklight`
3. to increase the brightness 10% from the current value simply type

   `$ xbacklight -inc 10`
4. to reduce the brightness 10% from the current value

   `$ xbacklight -dec 10`
5. perhaps it's necessary to set the range (example below)

   `$ xbacklight -set 50`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried exactly what you had mentioned but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Load the module sony-laptop.

`sudo modprobe sony-laptop`

Add it permanently to the loading list when the computer starts:

`echo sony-laptop | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`